# Shift+Cmd+D is copy-pasting prior line rather than documenting R package

Tags: r, rstudio, devtools, roxygen2

`Shift+Cmd+D` is listed as the standard [keyboard shortcut](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200711853-Keyboard-Shortcuts) for documenting packages in R, but lately `Shift+Cmd+D` has been copy-pasting the previous line of code rather than generating package documentation. I have re-installed devtools and roxygen2 but this has not fixed the problem.

Can anyone help me trouble shoot this?

Comment: This question is tangentially about [tag:r], but not about programming in the language itself. I've edited the tags to add [tag:rstudio] and remove [tag:r]. (Scratch that, you'll get better response with keeping [tag:r], though it's a little different ...)

Comment: If you go into Tools > Keyboard Shortcuts and filter by "Roxygen". Is the shortcut still listed here for "Roxygenize package"?

Comment: @AndersEllernBilgrau, yes it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to "Tools"->"Project Options"->"Build Tools"->Check "Generate documentation with Roxygen". This makes Ctrl+Shift+D work for me. Since it is in the projects options, I guess you have to opt in to use roxygen for every project. I don't know if there is a way to make this the default.